# How to include html file in another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two html files `first.html` and `second.html` and I want to include the second file into the first file for code re usability. I am using following statement to include the file:

```
<link rel="import" href="html file name here">
```

But it is not working. I tried using another solutions too, but none of them worked.

So give any suggestion.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this website.
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/imports/

It suggest what are the best practices. 
It always depends on your real needs. Why you didn't use frames?

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery:

```
a.html:

<html> 
  <head> 
<script src="jquery.js"></script> 
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#content").load("b.html"); 
});
</script> 
 </head> 

 <body> 
 <div id="content"></div>
</body> 
</html>

b.html:

<p> This is my second file </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

use jquery's `.load()` function to load your template.
Please refer this documentation. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the best solution is:

Using jQuery:

a.html:

```
<html> 
  <head> 
    <script src="jquery.js"></script> 
    <script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("b.html"); 
    });
    </script> 
  </head> 

  <body> 
     <div id="includedContent"></div>
  </body> 
</html>
b.html:

<p> This is my include file </p>
```

Like that i can get a simple and clean solution to my problem. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Source: [Include another HTML file in a HTML file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8988855/include-another-html-file-in-a-html-file)
Google is your friend :)