# Include another HTML file in a HTML file without java script

Tags: html

Ive a series of static html pages with a common footer, i want to inlcude content from the in each html file without duplication

e.g.

```
root
  page1.html
  page2.html
  page3.html
  footer.html
```

How do I make page 1,2 and 3 use the footer.html as the footer file without writing any java script. I've seen answers that included java script in this question [How to include html file in another html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651671/how-to-include-html-file-in-another-html-file) but I want to know if its possible without java script.

Remember

- These are static pages not running on a server
- This does not include the use of java script or other scripting process.     - The answers to [How to include html file in another html file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32651671/how-to-include-html-file-in-another-html-file) all use javascript and do not answer this question.

Comment: The only way is to use a frameset (which is deprecated AFAIK): https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/present/frames.html . Today you'd use a build step to compose your page with a template system, e.g. https://jekyllrb.com/ .

Comment: what framework/backend language are you using?

Comment: Perhaps look include [server side includes](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_include.html)

Comment: @EdHeal - I'm unsure how you propose that this would help, given that the OP stated in the original question "These are static pages not running on a server". Is this an oblique way of suggesting that they should? (be running on a server)

Answer (score 1):

[iframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) are HTML, they are very similar to PHP includes, but have much more security restrictions given the nature of open client based HTML compared to secure server based PHP.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      
      </style>
    </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h1>iframes</h1>
      </header>
    <main>
      <section>
        </section>
      </main>
    <footer>
      <iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
      <iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
      <iframe src="http://example.com"></iframe>
      </footer>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use html for this as html is static, if you want a dynamic webpage try to something like PHP.

Have a look at this : https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/how-to-include-php-headers-and-footers-on-html-site/

Hope it helps.